# How do you overlay an image on a shader in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, shaders

I'm trying to overlay an image on top of a shader to create the effect of having printed onto metal like so:

[image: Picture of a illy coffee can]

I'm using an Anisotropic shader for the underlying brushed metal and have UV Mapped a PNG (with alpha channel) for the printed portions. I've tried using a Mix and an Add shader to combine the two but it doesn't give the effect I'm after. Instead, it looks like the metal was stained with a translucent film, rather than over-printed with an opaque ink/paint.

Here's my shader so far:
[image: Screen grab of Node editor]

How can I achieve this over-printed effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the *Alpha* socket from your image, and plug it in to the *Fac* of the *Mix Shader* node. Then switch the *Diffuse BSDF* to the bottom socket of the *Mix Shader*, and the *Anisotropic BSDF* to the top shader socket.

The black and white alpha channel will control which parts of the material get which node. A value of 0 goes to the bottom socket and a value of 1 goes to the top socket.