# Putting transparent image on curved surface with specific placement (UV)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, image, faces

I'm very new to Blender, so please bear with me with this (hopefully) easy to answer question. :) Just to get this cleared: I searched for a total of 4 hours to find a solution to this problem, but I couldn't find any!

[image: Blimp that I want to put a text on (the text is an image)]

As you can see in the picture, I was trying to create a model of a blimp, which worked fine so far.

Now I'm trying to put a text on the front part of the airship, about at the location of the selected faces (see picture). I'm not able to use the normal text tool in Blender, because the text is a logo which I can't recreate using the keyboard.

All I want to do now is put the text on the said surface (and ONLY there, not wrapped around the entire ship) but in a realistic way, as if somebody put a sticker on it (the text should bend with the curve of the hull).

Ideally, I'd be able to move around the picture on the surface until it sits perfectly where I want it.

I'm using Cycles Render because thats what the guy in the tutorials used that I followed on YouTube.

Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/cycles-option-to-turn-off-texture-tiling and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19039/how-do-you-overlay-an-image-on-a-shader-in-cycles

Comment: Does your Blimp have a texture or a colour?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov So far I only applied a material to it, I haven't touched the texture section. From what I've understood so far, I'll have to use these "nodes", but I have no idea how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to your node set up of your material for your blimp and add a Mix RGB node in which you will plug your transparent texture in the bottom color and the alpha of your texture to the factor of the Mix RGB node. Your color for the whole blimp should go to the upper color, finally you plug the Mix RGB node to your Diffuse node and then to your Material Output/Surface. *Don't Forget to unwrap the part of the blimp you want your transparent texture to be assigned.

[image]

p.s. if you want to have textures insted of colors you will have to create a second UV map, *don't forget to give your texture node the right UV map.

[image]

For more information I can recommend you this tutorial: *the blender version is quite old but the process is the same: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnmovLzKU44

Comment: It almost worked! (Thanks so far!) Here's however what it looks like right now: http://imgur.com/VZtUVS6 As you can see, the image is repeated and distorted (and part of it is cut off). Is there any way I can make it appear in it's original proportions?

Comment: You can go to your UV window and Position/Scale your UVs on X or Y axis, also you can try to project from view

Comment: Okay that worked pretty good, the only problem I'm left with is the fact that the image is repeated. So, no matter how I scale it in the UV screen, there's always parts of the repeated image showing to the left and right ...

Comment: If you dont have to assign any textures to the left and to the right then you can just make sure these parts are separated by at least one loop cut from the place you need a texture, and just scale the parts (you don't need to have texture on) X = 0 and Y = 0 (in the UV window) and then drag them to the alpha part of the texture, this way they will not be able to display anything. (make sure you place the parts on alpha place of the texture)

Comment: You might want to use two different materials.  One material is for the plain blimp and uses the first UV map.  The second material is for the text area and is almost identical to the plain blimp material.  Its difference is that is has a second texture that uses the text-only UV map (each texture in a single material can use a different UV map)

Comment: to stop the image in the texture from repeating see this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21208/1853