# adding a transparent label on material

Tags: uv, node-editor

I am sure this has something to do with my nodes... but I got the label to be transparent.. however.. it's making the actual object it's placed on transparent NOT the label itself.. I think. Please see picture.

[image]

Comment: Unplug the transparent node from upper Shader socket of the Mix Shader and plug it below.. Diffuse BSDF goes to the upper socket of Mix Shader. Transparent BSDF goes to the bottom one (if it doesn't work set them inverse). Diffuse BSDF and Transparent BSDF don't need to be connected. The rest stay the same as on your picture. Quite long instruction manual, but it should work :).

Comment: Even when going with the "transparent BSDF goes to the bottom one (if it doesn't work set them inverse)" or going the reverse -- Still having issues. The background of the label makes the object transparent OR the switching the nodes pulgins as directed just makes the letter go transparent of the object.  See the screen shot... http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/uvmapping.jpg

Comment: Try to set the Image Texture type from 'Color' to 'Non-Color Data'. Maybe this will help?

Comment: Changing to non-color made the black label text a light gray is all -- same issues remain as before.

Comment: Marc, your .blend doesn't contain textures. Please pack the textures into your file and upload it again (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm).

Comment: I'm Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by pack the textures, is that something I do inside Blender? Because I added the label in the zip file but maybe because it's not that same directory structure as was on my computer it doesn't show up in the blender file and needs to be reassigned or placed?

Comment: @marc by default the blend file does not save the images in the file, you need to go to file->external data->pack_All_into_.blend and re-save the file. then the images will be part of the blend file.

Comment: Packed and Reuploaded. Thank you. Oh.. and I switched label graphics  thinking it might be something with the graphic.. but the same thing happens.

Comment: [How do you overlay an image on a shader in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19039/2217)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the part with the label has a different material than the rest of the copper container.

Go into edit mode and make all of the object have the same copper material

[image]

Now that everything is copper then add the label texture and transparency to the node tree:

[image]

The texture should fall into place since the only faces that have a UV map are the ones you chose for the label.

[image]

Comment: Whoa. You did it Cegaton! That is so complex. Thank you very much.