# How to add image texture 'layer' onto material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I'm new to Blender and I have another problem:

I've got myself nice, shiny material on my space ship, however it's really clean and now I want to add some details to it - stripes, logos, text etc.

Basically, I want to make it like it's another layer in Photoshop with different images.

How do I connect these logos textures to my existing nodes?

[image: what i have]

*Node setup:*
[image: nodes]

*What I want to achieve:*
[image: what i want]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to apply an image texture over a glass or plastic material?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/what-is-the-right-way-to-apply-an-image-texture-over-a-glass-or-plastic-material) or [adding a transparent label on material](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41321/adding-a-transparent-label-on-materiall)

Comment: Yes, this question looks similiar to mine, however I'm gonna need help with setting up nodes

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Considering [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8P3l.png) taken from the first link, you just have to substitute the "plastic" shader with the output coming from your last "Mix shader" (that represents your base shader).

Comment: What is 'De-Tile' node? Also when I add my logo texture, it applies to whole mesh, not couple selected faces where I want it.

Comment: The node prevents the tiling of the uv map. It basically exclude what's outside the UV box from bening considered. In connection with a proper unwrap it should  help you in keeping the image visble only where you want.

Comment: As for the "de-tile" nodegroup, it's no longer needed in 2.76+ as you can now set the coordinate extension mode to "clip" on the image texture node. In case you still want to use the node group, see [the question linked from my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/cycles-option-to-turn-off-texture-tiling/1272#1272).